# Products uploaded to Google Shop are not getting deleted form Magento Admin

Tags: magento, google-shopping

I have some product on Google Shopping (For my client). I want to delete the expired products from Google shop using Magento Admin.

I am  using **Magento 1.6**

```
Catalog > Google content > Manage Items
```

When I select the expired product and try to delete it. I am getting error `"Item xyz product has not been deleted"`
.

```
"No items were deleted from Google Content"
```

My xyz product is having quantity 0 in magento admin and it is disabled also.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this link and problem solved

https://collaborate.magento.com/magento/topics/problem_with_google_content_products

1) I updated Information in `System > Configuration > Google API > Google Shopping.`

I entered the correct username and password ( which my client provided, previously he has entered some other username and password.).
Make sure the Target Country is correct.

2) Then go to Catalog > Google Content > Manage Items and synchronize an item.

On synchronising item, item deleted successfully. Issue was that the items were visible in admin in magento.But not present in Google. So when I was trying to delete the product I was getting error.

If I tried deleting the product without any synchronisation after updating the username and password.I got following error.

```
Error code: notfound. Internal reason: item not found See 'request' for product 'xyz' (in 'English' store). 
No items were deleted from Google Content (because the products were not on Google)
```

Synchronization worked for me.